# Cannot set a variable using <input> javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have two webpages. One called index.html and one called invoice.html. I have a button that calls a function, which sets the variable "customerName" to an input tag I have with the ID of personName.

```
<input placeholder="John Smith" type="text" id="personName"></input>
<button type="submit" onclick="getCustomerInfo()">CREATE INVOICE</button>
```

Then the function gets called and runs this code.

```
var customerName = document.getElementById('personName').value;
```

Now on the invoice.html, I try to use the variable customerName to set the value of another input with the ID txtName, by calling another function, with another button on that web page.

```
<button type="button" onclick="customerInvoice()">PLACE ORDER</button>
document.getElementById('txtName').value = customerName;
```

However, after all this, the input stays blank. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick. Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. There is no state maintained between HTML pages. You need to submit data to a server and then place it in the new page using server-side code or use AJAX to talk to a server. If I've missed someting you think should work, please post a more complere example.

Answer (score 0):

Its works as a object constructor function so to set a value you need to use:

```
document.getElementById('txtName').value = new customerName;
```

because you can use a constructor to set value in a new variable, but its no the same to set a variable value in a constructor function.